# Physics Journal Club on chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

The original idea comes form CrossValidated (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/674/first-cross-validated-journal-club) and [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/second-cross-validated-journal-club)); basically, each month users propose and select in voting one not too specific, yet intriguing or simply interesting OpenAcess paper that is later discussed during a special chat session.

Do you think we should try to implement it on Physics?

Comment: Sounds like there's significant interest.  Would you like to start the meta thread for the first meeting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea. We might even be able to use it to bring people into the site, because these chat sessions might make good events to advertise (although I suppose it'd be a bit of a pain for someone who doesn't already have an SE account to get one just to participate in the chat). Also, if we are able to successfully invite any authors, we could perhaps make a good impression on them and gain their support for the site.

Comment: I don't think it will be a pain to register. They can use the OpenID stuff.

Comment: Hmmm, how will we get the message to possible candidates? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Speaking on the "chat" side of things, I think that has much merit re community building - my thoughts:

- use a dedicated room for the purpose; not the local "tavern" room (if you see what I mean)
- perhaps put up a scheduled event advert (the room owners can do this via the "events" tab)
- note that *normally* anyone talking would need to have legitimately gained the nominal (it really is small) minimum rep
- if there is a *legitimate* guest-speaker (i.e. the paper's author / experts etc), the system *does support* allowing them to talk, but this is now a moderator-only function - use sensibly please ;p And as you say, this may "suck them in"...

Actually, as part of general site advocacy I think I'd happily see things like this on a *range* of sites.

Comment: Yeah, I have already gone through most of those issues; the minimum reputation may be a problem since it seems the club itself may be more attractive than the site.