# Would Q's that require reading a particular paper be useful to Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, tags, questions

It has become clear to me that the CPR idea redacted below is *waaay* too complex to succeed. The less ambitious **["Journal Club"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/lets-have-a-journal-club)** idea of 2 years ago was enthusiastically received, then fizzled. I feel that was too ambitious also.

More realistically, I would propose that there can be questions based on particular papers, preprints or articles that can only be sensibly answered if that paper has been read. Perhaps with a *research-paper* tag? The question can be as basic as "what do you think of this paper?".

This could achieve some of the goals of a "Journal Club", such as providing higher level content, without the off-putting procedural overhead.

Comment: I've deleted a large number of comments inspired by an earlier version of this post and relating to Physics Overflow.

Comment: So basically you want to resurrect the [journal club](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/lets-have-a-journal-club) that kinda went nowhere?

Comment: Also, I've (again) removed completely irrelevant tags.

Comment: @KyleKanos, we were editing at the same time, broken lines, and I stepped on your edit. Probably the same edits anyway, except for tags.

Comment: No, my edit was accepted. The irrelevant tags are still gone.

Comment: --- 
So basically you want to resurrect the journal club that kinda went nowhere?
---
No. Reading the journal club discussion now.

Comment: Actually yes. I initially misunderstood the Journal proposition to suggest assignments and scheduled meetings, which would NOT be good.

How about a special kind of paper review question where in order to answer you need to read a certain paper. OR, a question that is actually a paper review by the PO.

Comment: Please, no scheduled chats.

Comment: @KyleKanos, since I have COMPLETELY reformulated the Question, can we start over on the voting?

Comment: @Aabaakawad No, that's not how this site works. You *could* try to ask a new question (again).

Comment: @Aabaakawad: I've removed my downvote (always possible after an edit), but I concur with Danu's answer that your proposal really is already on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposal as it currently stands (v12) is pretty much vacuous: The type of questions that you propose is *already* on-topic on this site. They typically do not attract much attention or a great answer, because the chances that someone here has read [insert random arXiv paper] is pretty small, and most people wouldn't read an entire paper just to answer a question on this site. However, they're definitely allowed and thus you're not proposing anything new. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189617/question-about-blandford-znajek-original-paper) is a typical example.

Comment: Yeah, just trying figure out how we ever could get reviewing papers going. The Journal Club idea looks really well thought out, yet it did not go anywhere, so I guess I have to accept that reviewing papers is just not going to happen.

Comment: Well, "what do you think of this paper" is not a good question for us (I don't know if that was in the question when you answered). But in general, the idea that questions about a specific research paper are on topic is totally true.

Comment: @DavidZ indeed, that would not be a good question, and that wasn't what I answered to :-)